# AKS Pod status ContainerStatusUnknown with exit code 137

Tags: kubernetes, containers, azure-aks, containerstatusunknown

I have a AKS cluster and it has one Node pool with 1 node and the Autoscaling was Enabled to Max 5 nodes. I noticed that, there are few pods are not running and shows error,

`cert-manager-XXX  1/1  Running`

`cert-manager-XXX  0/1  ContainerStatusUnknown`

`cert-manager-XXX  0/1  Completed`

`cert-manager-XXX  1/1  Running`

So, when I described the pod, it shows

`Reason: ContainerStatusUnknown`

`Message: The container could not be located when the pod was terminated`

`Exit Code: 137`

And, when I checked for pod logs, it shows

`unable to retrieve container logs for containerd:XXXXXX`

How do I fix this issue? is this related to OOM?